# Gracefully shutdown PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, unix, signals, phantomjs, kill-process

I'm setting up a PhantomJS rendering server, and it seems that phantomjs has a memory leak.
I would like to regulary kill the process and start a new one, as I do not have a more elegant solution for the moment.

Is anyone aware of a way to make PhantomJS *gracefully* shut down (wait for any pending request to finish, and then exit)? Maybe using Unix signals?